# PCA: Calculating variance of projected data - sample variance or population variance?

Tags: pca

Given 3 data points (-1,1), (0,0), and (1,1), I am asked to apply PCA and find the projected data points. Then calculate the variance of the projected data.

I applied eigenvalue decomposition and found the projected data points as -sqrt(2),0, sqrt(2) i.e., the 2d points are now projected onto 1d space. Should I use the population variance formula or the sample variance formula to calculate the variance?

Comment: When you applied PCA, how did you compute the variance?  Just be consistent.